# Graphical parameters in ggplot2: How to change axis/tick thickness

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just started using 'ggplot2', and am running into some problems with the graphical usability.

I wanted to do a simple regression biplot. However, I am not quite convinced by the themes offered by 'ggplot2' and 'ggthemes'.

My code thus far is as follows:

```
    ggplot(data, aes(APE.15N, APE.13C)) +
        geom_point(size=3) +
        geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F, col="black") +
        theme_light(base_size = 20) + 
        annotate("text", x=.9, y=1.35, label="R²=0.3192, p<0.001", size=6.5) +
        coord_cartesian(xlim = c(.25, 1.1), ylim = c(1.05, 2.55)) +
        ylab(expression(paste('APE '^{13}, "C", sep = ""))) +
        xlab(expression(paste('APE '^{15}, "N", sep = "")))
```

...which gives me the following plot:

[ouput from R with ggplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWUks.png)

Now, I would like to increase the axis-line thickness as well as the tick thickness to at least 2 points, add minor ticks, get rid of the background grid, and change the axis colour to black.

I just can't figure out how...

I would imagine the result as in the following graph:

[example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NSdf.png)

Thank you,
your help is very much appreciated

Comment: `?theme` should give you an idea.

Comment: If the answer below suits needs, please mark it as correct (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 28):

To increase the axis-line thickness and change the color to black:
`axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black', size = 2)`

To increase the tick thickness:
`axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size = 2)`

To add minor ticks:
Minor ticks are not currently an option of ggplot2. There are many other stackoverflow questions about minor ticks that I would suggest looking at. You can try adding `minor_breaks` in `scale_x_continuous`, but that would require a knowing the actual minor ticks you want.

To remove the background grid:
`panel.grid.major = element_blank()`, `panel.grid.minor = element_blank()`

Comment: This is useful, thanks. Just to clarify, the `axis.line = etc` call should come within `theme()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.