# Tick mark in line with border when expand = c(0, 0) - axis ticks do not seem to align with axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using

```
expand = c(0, 0)
```

to remove the space between the zero and the border of the graph. However, the tick mark is then half on and half off the border when I save it as a png.

[image: detail of graph]

Is there any way of making the tick mark be in line with the border, which would look way more elegant?
I tried making the border thicker, but that doesn't solve it.

```
df<-data.frame(x=c("T1", "T2", "T3"), y=c(48, 24, 26))
ggplot(data=df, aes(x, y))+
  geom_col()+ 
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 60), breaks=c(0, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60))
```

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474643/graphical-parameters-in-ggplot2-how-to-change-axis-tick-thickness The answer in the link has a number of useful tips.

Comment: @LeroyTyrone this is not a dupe. But the linked question is still interesting, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @LeroyTyrone Yes, you are correct. It is a duplicate. The word 'align' was what was missing from my search. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy fix would be to use `coord_cartesian(clip="off")` to prevent the axis line from being clipped off when hitting the panel border:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("T1", "T2", "T3"), y = c(48, 24, 26))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = c(0, 0),
    limits = c(0, 60),
    breaks = c(0, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60)
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]